# Function result inside CompositeDisposable inside subscribe

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 function for API connection:

```
//Load data from API
private fun loadData() {
    compositeDisposable.add(
        ApiClient.getClient.getQuestions(Params.getParamsSearch())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse)
    )
}

//Response handler for API
private fun handleResponse(objectsQueryResult: ObjectsQueryResult) {
    updateAdapter(objectsQueryResult)

}
```

What is the syntax to put all lines in handleResponse function inside subscribe instead of using the function?

Something like this:

```
//Load data from API
private fun loadData() {
    compositeDisposable.add(
        ApiClient.getClient.getQuestions(Params.getParamsSearch())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe({
updateAdapter(objectsQueryResult)
 })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.subscribe({ objectsQueryResult ->
    updateAdapter(objectsQueryResult)
})
```

or

```
.subscribe({
    updateAdapter(it)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
//Load data from API
private fun loadData() {
    compositeDisposable.add(
        ApiClient.getClient.getQuestions(Params.getParamsSearch())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe { objectsQueryResult -> updateAdapter(objectsQueryResult) }
    )
}
```

or

```kotlin
//Load data from API
private fun loadData() {
    compositeDisposable.add(
        ApiClient.getClient.getQuestions(Params.getParamsSearch())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe { updateAdapter(it) }
    )
}
```